# How to tell exactly what packages have security updates in Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, ubuntu-14.04, automatic-updates

I'm trying to get a list of packages that are marked as having "security updates"

My base system is Ubuntu 14.04

For example, there is a script on Ubuntu 14.04 which will list number of updates available. The dynamic-ish motd uses it.

```
/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check
```

Running that with no args gives semicolon-separated output to stderr, e.g.:

```
$ /usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check
60;11   <-- (this is actually standard error)
```

There are "human readable" and "package names" flags for this script. Great! But "package names" just dumps out the packages being updated, it doesn't put them into security/non-security piles.

How can I tell what's in the "security updates" bucket?

I've tried things like:

```
apt-get -s dist-upgrade | grep "^Inst" | grep -i security
```

That one isn't working for me.

I'm considering taking the apt-check script apart and re-using it, but I'd like to know if there's an existing facility to do what I want before I do that.

**Update**

I ended up modifying the python script "/usr/lib/update-notifier/apt-check" and basically adding output to print the package details whenever that script did a check with the "isSecurityUpgrade()" function. (See that script for details)

Comment: Your command works for me on both Ubuntu and Debian systems. If you run apt-get -s upgrade, do you see "security" in the output?

Comment: Nope, I do not see "security" in the output. I figured I would. I've tried this on a handful of boxes, including ones that "apt-check" thinks has security updates available

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: And my apologies for not asking in comments but I'm too new and don't have the rep.

If you're looking for just those coming from security repos I use the below with cron to email me once a week from our un-monitored servers.

```
#!/bin/bash

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
#- Name....: checkSecurityupdates.sh
#- Notes...:
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------#

# create fresh securities file each run
grep "-security" /etc/apt/sources.list | sudo grep -v "#" > /etc/apt/security.sources.list
echo "created security specific source list"


# Create the security file list
echo 'n' | apt-get upgrade -o Dir::Etc::SourceList=/etc/apt/security.sources.list >> /root/securities-to-update.txt
echo "created list of security updates"



# What's the mimetype
get_mimetype(){
  # warning: assumes that the passed file exists
  file --mime-type "$1" | sed 's/.*: //'
}


# some variables

from="SecUpdates-Report@example.com"
to="monitor-this-mailbox@example.com"
subject=`hostname`
boundary="ZZ_/afg6432dfgkl.94531q"
body="Please see attached"
declare -a attachments
attachments=( "securities-to-update.txt" )

# Build headers
{

printf '%s\n' "From: $from
To: $to
Subject: $subject
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$boundary\"

--${boundary}
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"US-ASCII\"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: inline

$body
"

# now loop over the attachments, guess the type
# and produce the corresponding part, encoded base64
for file in "${attachments[@]}"; do

  [ ! -f "$file" ] && echo "Warning: attachment $file not found, skipping" >&2 && continue

  mimetype=$(get_mimetype "$file")

  printf '%s\n' "--${boundary}
Content-Type: $mimetype
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"
"

  base64 "$file"
  echo
done

# print last boundary with closing --
printf '%s\n' "--${boundary}--"

} | sendmail -t -oi   
echo "sent security updates list"



# cleanup security files
rm /etc/apt/security.sources.list
rm /root/securities-to-update.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. I think using the apt-get flag "--assume-no" may be cleaner than piping 'n' to the command. but this is helpful, thanks

Comment: I tested this method and the output list of packages being upgraded does not at all match the list that is produced when just using the security sources.list. I really don't understand why this would be

Comment: You're right about the list not matching and I believe that is due to the dependencies being shown but double check that. If you run the actual update against that security sources file generated though I get a set of packages kept back but the rest upgraded... Post your solution as an answer too in case it helps out others.